# Deployed war file to docker image cannot be accessed from TOMCAT 8 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, docker, tomcat8

**My Docker File**

```
# Pull base image
  FROM tomcat:8-jre8

# Maintainer
  MAINTAINER "Ravindu <rav@info.com">

# Copy to images tomcat path
  ADD /mobile.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

The docker image is built through running maven ant plugin, which successfully creates the image without any problem. But when I run the created image the tomcat server is starting as normal and **throwing following errors on stack trace**

```
19-Mar-2017 07:33:11.517 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/mobile]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@3ec80848]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4969)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5099)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@1c19c6e4]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:707)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:110)
    ... 17 more

19-Mar-2017 07:33:11.519 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/mobile.war
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/mobile]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:757)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Though I can access the tomcat server landing page via obtaining the docker container IP, even after these errors occur, my desired war file route which is the  /mobile cannot be accessed and throws a 404.

**N.B.** - I have even tried to create a image directly using the docker file without using maven ant plugin, but the issue still remains same when running the created docker image.

**N.B.** - Though it throws a Zip file empty error, the mobile.war file is extracted completely without any error in my ubuntu machine.

**N.B.** - Also I tried doing this on my windows machine using docker toolbox command line tool, by creating an image based on the same Dockerfile and I was able to successfully deploy and access my war file via /mobile without any problem.

**N.B.** - mobile.war file is created with default maven war plugin and I'm using IntelliJ IDEA for my development.

**EDIT** - Adding the Full Stack Trace

```
WARNING: Error loading config file:/home/ravindu/.docker/config.json - stat /home/ravindu/.docker/config.json: permission denied
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
22-Mar-2017 10:50:17.386 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.42
22-Mar-2017 10:50:17.395 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Mar 8 2017 19:58:16 UTC
22-Mar-2017 10:50:17.395 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.42.0
22-Mar-2017 10:50:17.395 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
22-Mar-2017 10:50:17.395 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.4.0-66-generic
22-Mar-2017 10:50:17.395 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
22-Mar-2017 10:50:17.395 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
22-Mar-2017 10:50:17.395 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_121-8u121-b13-1~bpo8+1-b13
22-Mar-2017 10:50:17.396 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
22-Mar-2017 10:50:17.396 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/tomcat
22-Mar-2017 10:50:17.396 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/tomcat
22-Mar-2017 10:50:17.396 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
22-Mar-2017 10:50:17.396 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
22-Mar-2017 10:50:17.396 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
22-Mar-2017 10:50:17.396 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
22-Mar-2017 10:50:17.396 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/tomcat/endorsed
22-Mar-2017 10:50:17.396 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat
22-Mar-2017 10:50:17.396 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat
22-Mar-2017 10:50:17.397 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp
22-Mar-2017 10:50:17.397 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.12 using APR version 1.5.1.
22-Mar-2017 10:50:17.397 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
22-Mar-2017 10:50:17.445 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.1.0e  16 Feb 2017)
22-Mar-2017 10:50:17.915 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
22-Mar-2017 10:50:17.939 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
22-Mar-2017 10:50:17.940 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 2425 ms
22-Mar-2017 10:50:18.034 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
22-Mar-2017 10:50:18.034 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.42
22-Mar-2017 10:50:18.131 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/mobile.war
22-Mar-2017 10:50:19.556 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/mobile]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@3954f4bc]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4969)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5099)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@3b4859b1]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:707)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:110)
    ... 17 more

22-Mar-2017 10:50:19.597 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/mobile.war
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/mobile]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:757)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

22-Mar-2017 10:50:19.618 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/mobile.war has finished in 1,467 ms
22-Mar-2017 10:50:19.633 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager
22-Mar-2017 10:50:20.542 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager has finished in 909 ms
22-Mar-2017 10:50:20.543 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs
22-Mar-2017 10:50:20.595 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs has finished in 52 ms
22-Mar-2017 10:50:20.596 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager
22-Mar-2017 10:50:20.632 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager has finished in 36 ms
22-Mar-2017 10:50:20.636 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
22-Mar-2017 10:50:20.697 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT has finished in 60 ms
22-Mar-2017 10:50:20.697 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples
22-Mar-2017 10:50:21.239 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples has finished in 542 ms
22-Mar-2017 10:50:21.245 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
22-Mar-2017 10:50:21.284 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
22-Mar-2017 10:50:21.292 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 3351 ms
```

Couldn't find any exact lead to solve this issue even after referring lots of SO questions.

Comment: Are you sure that the WAR file is actually copied into the container? You're using `/mobile.war` for the local WAR file - are you sure this file exists in your host system's root folder? Are you sure you don't want to use `./mobile.war` instead?

Comment: I can see my mobile.war file within the container. Its extracting without any issue!

Comment: Can you try changing the tomcat version like "FROM tomcat:8.0.20-jre8". Not sure if it will help but nothing crazy in giving it a try.

Comment: Many thanks for the tip @SanketD! But it's not solved! The same error still exists!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be two issues in this case :

1. The best approach to copy files like `*.war,*.zip,.*.tar.gz` in container not with `ADD` but must use `COPY` because there is a little difference in `COPY` and `ADD`. When you use `ADD` it will put files in a extracted mode inside Images.if it is in any of these `.war,.zip,.*.tar.gz`, and if use `COPY` then it will simply just copy like `cp` command inside Images. So best practice is to use `COPY` for those kind of files and no worries of getting it corrupted.
2. As you mentioned in comments `"bash: jar: command not found"` may be your java inside container is not set up in `$PATH` variable or `JAVA_HOME`  don't have proper permission.

Hope this will help.Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Thought ADD could do more than COPY. Between adding COPY didn't solve the problem. The problem may be associated with your 2nd point. Will do more debugging and get back!

Comment: Great ! Giving you some more hint. Before putting this in docker just try to run `mobile.war` on your physical host. You can identify what is actually creating issue a war or a docker ?

Comment: The problem seems to be with docker! It's working fine in physical host!

Comment: Add `JAVA/jdk/jre` in your container and add `JAVA_HOME` in your `.bash_profile` then verify `javac` before starting your tomcat.I think issue is related to JAVA also provide proper permission to JAVA dir.Thank you!

Comment: The problem was certainly with my local machines java version. I did the same process within my AWS linux machine and it worked without any problems. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if `mobile.war` getting corrupted when copied to the container? I saw you mention that you are able to extract it on host machine but it could be possible the whole file is somehow not getting copied properly.

Get into your container using  `docker exec -it container-name bash`  then goto `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/` and check `jar xvf mobile.war`

Comment: Running this within the container throws "bash: jar: command not found"  error!

Comment: can you try removing the java, tomcat and your custom images and then rebuild it?

Comment: Do you mean the base docker images for tomcat? If that so tried it earlier before posting this question! Nothing progressive!